# Why does php datetime diff depend on time zones?

Tags: php, date, timezone, diff, intervals

See the following code:

```php
function printDiff($tz) {
    $d1 = new DateTime("2015-06-01", new DateTimeZone($tz));
    $d2 = new DateTime("2015-07-01", new DateTimeZone($tz));
    $diff = $d1->diff($d2);
    print($diff->format("Year: %Y Month: %M Day: %D"). PHP_EOL);
}
printDiff("UTC");
printDiff("Australia/Melbourne");
```

The result is:

```
Year: 00 Month: 01 Day: 00
Year: 00 Month: 00 Day: 30
```

Questions:

- How can the difference between the same day of two adjacent months (1st of June and July) be different than 1 month?
- Why does the computation mode depend on which timezone I use if there is no DST between the given days, there is no leap year, there is nothing special?
- Where can I find the exact description of the algorithm how the difference is computed?

Comment: FWIW, the difference between two dates in a vaguely defined unit like "month" is rather ambiguous anyway, so I wouldn't expect any particular consistent result. Interesting question (and answer) nonetheless.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *date* extension stores the time values in GMT. The GMT offset [is stored separately](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/timelib_structs.h#L244). It is applied at the late phases of calculations, for correction.

Particularly, `DateTime::diff` internally calls [`timelib_diff`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/interval.c#L28) function, which calculates difference between two dates, applies the DST correction, then normalizes its internal structures, in that order.

When both dates are in *UTC*, the function compares the following:

- `Timestamp=1433116800, year=2015, month=6, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0`
- `Timestamp=1435708800, year=2015, month=7, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0`

It subtracts years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds correspondingly. The difference is exactly one month. Therefore, the internal structures are not modified after [normalization](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/tm2unixtime.c#L77).

When both dates are in *Australia/Melbourne*, the function compares the following:

- `Timestamp=1433080800, year=2015, month=5, day=31, hour=14, minute=0, second=0`
- `Timestamp=1435672800, year=2015, month=6, day=30, hour=14, minute=0, second=0`

Both dates are obtained by subtracting 10 hours (the timezone offset without DST correction). As we have seen, the DST correction [is applied](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/interval.c#L69) after subtraction of the time values, if needed (it is not needed, in particular). The difference before normalization is:

```
0 years, 1 month, -1 day, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

Since we have an offset between the months, normalization function computes the difference as

```
0 years, 0 months, 30 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

The `DateInterval::format` method is straightforward. It just substitutes the placeholders to the members of [`timelib_rel_time`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/timelib_structs.h#L216) structure. That's why we get *1 month* for UTC, and *30 days* for Australia/Melbourne.

**The `a` format character**

That looks somewhat unreliable. However, there is a `days` member in the `timelib_rel_time` structure, which [always equals to the difference in days](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/interval.c#L74). The value is available via the `a` format character:

```
function printDiff($tz) {
  $d1 = new DateTime("2015-06-01", new DateTimeZone($tz));
  $d2 = new DateTime("2015-07-01", new DateTimeZone($tz));
  $diff = $d1->diff($d2);
  print($diff->format("Year: %Y Month: %M Day: %D days: %a"). PHP_EOL);
}

printDiff("UTC");
printDiff("Australia/Melbourne");
```

*Output*

```
Year: 00 Month: 01 Day: 00 days: 30
Year: 00 Month: 00 Day: 30 days: 30
```

**P.S.**

The values in this answer are obtained with the help of [`TIMELIB_DEBUG`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f19e3d3014d5a8771ce311af0ac01bb86e3d5667/ext/date/lib/timelib_structs.h#L314) macro.

Comment: Thank you, Ruslan. It explains a lot of things and it is totally clear now. I am still unsure if this is the correct (i.e. intuitively expected) behaviour but it explains it very precisely. Thanks.