# Get diff between two dates

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Can anyone explain why PHP calculates the diff between two dates differently depending on what timezone was given?

```php
$A = new DateTime('2000-02-01 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$B = new DateTime('2000-03-01 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

$ABdiff = $A->diff($B); 

var_dump($ABdiff->m); // int(1)

// versus

$X = new DateTime('2000-02-01 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$Y = new DateTime('2000-03-01 00:00:00', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));

$XYdiff = $X->diff($Y); 

var_dump($XYdiff->m); // int(0)
```

I dont quite understand why the timezone affects the calculation here.

Comment: If you `var_dump($XYdiff);` you will see the difference (hint look at the days)

Comment: This is a good answer for another question :)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for pointing to the right answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354442/why-does-php-datetime-diff-depend-on-time-zones)!