# PHP DateTime->diff() doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, datetime

I met an interesting case, related to the `diff()` method of `DateTime` class.

If I try to calculate difference between two dates in months like

```
$datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019');
$datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m');
```

, as result I get `0`.

Why does this happen?

Print_r's:

$datetime1:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000000 
[timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
```

$datetime2:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000000 
[timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
```

$interval:

```
DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 30 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [f] => 0 
[weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 
[invert] => 0 [days] => 30 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0
 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

Comment: Strange, I get `1`

Comment: The difference is 30 days, so that would only count as some months.

Comment: And a DateInterval Object of `DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 1
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 30
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)`

Comment: Can depend of the timezone of the server, I got 0 too

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ I get 1 too.

Comment: `var_dump($interval);` - check what that contains. You’re likely to see `d` with value `30` in there.

Comment: @VincentDecaux why it can depend of the timezone?)) What's the relation between?

Comment: @montie I don't know, but if somepeople have the problem, and other don't, there is somehting

Comment: @misorude yes, I see, but a month can have also 31 days))

Comment: If you add the 3 lines what do you get? `print_r($datetime1);
print_r($datetime2);
print_r($interval);` Please add result to your question as extra data

Comment: Stranger! Even when I use `Europe/Berlin` as a timezone I still get `1 month`

Comment: But as you can see you are getting 30 days as @jeroen was suggesting. Yea, what version of PHP are you using

Comment: Even when I use `Feb 2019` and `Mar 2019` I still get `1M` using PHP7.3.3

Comment: And with 7.0 and 7.1 and 7.,2 and 5.6 and 5.5

Comment: This is already answered. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354442/why-does-php-datetime-diff-depend-on-time-zones

Comment: According to the comment by @AshokGadri you can use the `%a` format to get the correct number of days instead of months.

Comment: @montie please review my answer below; I have found an interest inconsistency and a possible (but imperfect) workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your timezone.

There is a post explaining about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354442/why-does-php-datetime-diff-depend-on-time-zones).

See this example:

```
<?php

echo "----- Europe/Berlin -----\n";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); 
$datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019');
$datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019');
print_r($datetime1);
print_r($datetime2);

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
print_r($interval);

echo "%m = " . $interval->format('%m') . PHP_EOL;
echo "%a = " . $interval->format('%a') . PHP_EOL;
echo "%s = " . $interval->format('%s') . PHP_EOL;


echo "\n\n\n----- America/Sao_Paulo -----\n";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); 
$datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019');
$datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019');
print_r($datetime1);
print_r($datetime2);

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
print_r($interval);

echo "%m = " . $interval->format('%m') . PHP_EOL;
echo "%a = " . $interval->format('%a') . PHP_EOL;
echo "%s = " . $interval->format('%s') . PHP_EOL;
```

And the output:

```
$ php date_diff.php 
----- Europe/Berlin -----
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 30
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 30
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
%m = 0
%a = 30
%s = 0



----- America/Sao_Paulo -----
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Sao_Paulo
)
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 1
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 30
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
%m = 1
%a = 30
%s = 0
```

In my timezone `$interval->format('%m');` is 1.

You can set timezone on your dates to calculate the difference between them.

```
$datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
print_r($interval);
echo "%m = " . $interval->format('%m') . PHP_EOL;
```

```
$ php date_diff.php 
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 1
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [f] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 30
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
%m = 1
```

Comment: But in the real world there is no difference between month length depending on time zone...

Comment: I just edited the answer by adding the reference.
Look: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354442/why-does-php-datetime-diff-depend-on-time-zones]

Answer (score 2):

## There is big inconsistency with timezone and date handing in PHP

This appears to be a bug (in so far as the datetime format is forced to a GMT* offset, [according to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007401/php-datetime-diff-doesnt-work-correctly/57008325#comment100549208_57007401)).

*(but forcing to GMT seems inconsistent with the results established by the code below)

Setting the server timezone value to any timezone does not effect this script timezone anomaly.

Below are two cases showing what happens in different time zones:

---

## Case 1:

The following code will output a list of results for each time zone:

```
$tzList = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);

print "Current Zone:". print_r(ini_get('date.timezone'),true)."<br>\n<BR>\n";

foreach($tzList as $tzRow) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzRow);
    //$tz = null;
    $datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019', $tz);
    $datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019', $tz);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2, false);
    echo $interval->format('%a %m') . PHP_EOL. " :: ";

    print print_r($datetime1->getTimezone(),true)."<BR>";
}
```

The result of this list output shows a high (~60%) rate of `0` and the rest of `1` month .

Please see here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b18ba13deb94d112b12630a12265363fb6c7670b

---

## Case 2:

Setting the timezone AFTER creating the object, results in a consistent answer (albeit incorrect)

```
$tzList = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);

print "Current Zone:". print_r(ini_get('date.timezone'),true)."<br>\n<BR>\n";

foreach($tzList as $tzRow) {
    //$tz = new DateTimeZone($tzRow);
    $tz = null;
    $datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019', $tz);
    $datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019', $tz);
    $datetime1->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tzRow));
    $datetime2->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tzRow));
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2, false);
    echo $interval->format('%a %m') . PHP_EOL. " :: ";

    print print_r($datetime1->getTimezone(),true)."<BR>";
}
```

This output's generated here all **all** 30 days out; but **all** 0 months difference.

See code here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7bcc62f4e36f41df71b9cb928de75a53f233d9fd

---

So it's your choice if you want to use sometimes correct results or universally incorrect rbut consistent results, by setting *when* you establish the Timezone value in the DateTime objects.

---

## Possible Solution:

If the server timezone is correctly set to UTC "correct" timezone (that naturally returns "1" month in `Case 1`, then **CASE 2** above works consistently across all time zones given to the DateTime objects.

Comment: Also, another working solution, in this case,  is to put concrete date in front of month and year in both of arguments. Respectively: "1 June 2019" and "31 July 2019".

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it by adding a timezone?

```
$timezones = [
    'UTC',
    'Europe/Berlin',
    'America/Belize',
    'Asia/Hong_Kong',
];

foreach ($timezones as $timezone) {
    $tz = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    $datetime1 = new \DateTime('June 2019', $tz);
    $datetime2 = new \DateTime('July 2019', $tz);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo str_pad($timezone, 20, ' ').' '.$interval->format('months: %M,  day: %D,  days: %a') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
UTC                  months: 01,  day: 00,  days: 30
Europe/Berlin        months: 00,  day: 30,  days: 30
America/Belize       months: 01,  day: 00,  days: 30
Asia/Hong_Kong       months: 00,  day: 30,  days: 30
```

Comment: UTC results in 1, where Europe/Berlin results in 0 for me

Comment: Using `%a` as a format will always return the same value in days