# PHP DateTime Diff 2019-12-01 -> 2019-11-01 Month Zero?

Tags: php, datetime, diff

i have a huge problem with datetime difference. When i compare this two dates 2019-12-01 and 2019-11-01, there is only 30 days difference and no month, why?

```
$date2 = new DateTime('2019-12-01');
$date1 = new DateTime("2019-11-01");
$diff = $date1->diff($date2, true)->m;
echo "Difference should be 1 month: ".$diff;
```

Comment: `$diff` is giving me `1` as expected - So what is your question?

Comment: gives me 0 on PHP 5.6, 1 on PHP 7.2, guess it's a version problem.

Comment: It depends on the timezone, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354442/why-does-php-datetime-diff-depend-on-time-zones

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z");
$date1 = new DateTime("2019-11-01T00:00:00Z");
$diff = $date1->diff($date2, true)->m;
echo "Difference should be 1 month: ".$diff;
```

The **T** doesn't really stand for anything. It is just the separator that the [ISO 8601 combined date-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) format requires. You can read it as an abbreviation for Time.

The **Z** stands for the Zero timezone, as it is offset by 0 from the [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#UTC).

Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282022/7935051)

See [demo](https://3v4l.org/EW6uM) here